# Route.get() requires callback functions but got a "object Undefined"

Tags: node.js, express

I am learning making Todo app.
On the website, I am studying is https://coderwall.com/p/4gzjqw/build-a-javascript-todo-app-with-express-jade-and-mongodb

I typed as instruction describes,

**app.js**

```js
var main = require('./routes/main');
var todo = require('./routes/todo');
var todoRouter = express.Router();
app.use('/todos', todoRouter);
app.get('/', main.index);
todoRouter.get('/',todo.all);
todoRouter.post('/create', todo.create);
todoRouter.post('/destroy/:id', todo.destroy);
todoRouter.post('/edit/:id', todo.edit);
```

**/routes/todo.js**

```js
module.exports ={
  all: function(req, res){
    res.send('All todos');
  },
  viewOne: function(req, res){
    console.log('Viewing '+req.params.id);
  },
  create: function(req, res){
    console.log('Todo created');
  },
  destroy: function(req, res){
    console.log('Todo deleted');
  },
  edit: function(req, res){
    console.log('Todo '+req.params.id+' updated');
  }
};
```

and I got this error message

> Error: Route.get() requires callback functions but got a [object
> Undefined]

Did I miss something here?

Comment: Next step, it asks create other file, main.js and jade template, then it works. I don't know what happens

Answer (score 39, accepted):

In the tutorial the `todo.all` returns a `callback` object. This is required for the `router.get` syntax.

From the documentation:

> **router.METHOD(path, [callback, ...] callback)**
>
> The router.METHOD() methods provide the routing functionality in
>   Express, where METHOD is one of the HTTP methods, such as GET, PUT,
>   POST, and so on, in lowercase. Thus, the actual methods are
>   router.get(), router.post(), router.put(), and so on.

You still need to define the array of `callback` objects in your `todo` files so you can access the proper `callback` object for your `router`.

You can see from your tutorial that `todo.js` contains the array of `callback` objects (this is what you are accessing when you write `todo.all`):

```
module.exports = {
    all: function(req, res){
        res.send('All todos')
    },
    viewOne: function(req, res){
        console.log('Viewing ' + req.params.id);
    },
    create: function(req, res){
        console.log('Todo created')
    },
    destroy: function(req, res){
        console.log('Todo deleted')
    },
    edit: function(req, res){
        console.log('Todo ' + req.params.id + ' updated')
    }
};
```

Answer (score 61):

I got the same error.
After debugging, I found that I misspelled the method name that I imported from the controller into the route file.
Please check the method name.

Comment: In my case, I renamed already implemented method by mistake :)

Comment: You Sir, are my hero!

Comment: It's always the most unexpected mistake... 

Comment: Copilot got me into trouble. Thanks buddy!

Answer (score 13):

Some time you miss below line. add this router will understand this.

```
module.exports = router;
```

Comment: happened to me. I mistyped as "module.export" not "module.exports"

Answer (score 10):

There are two routes for get:

```
app.get('/', main.index);
todoRouter.get('/',todo.all);
```

*Error: Route.get() requires callback functions but got a [object Undefined]*
This exception is thrown when `route.get`does not get a callback function. As you have defined todo.all in todo.js file, but it is unable to find main.index. 
That's why it works once you define main.index file later on in the tutorial.

Answer (score 9):

Make sure that:

yourFile.js:

```
exports.yourFunction = function(a,b){
  //your code
}
```

Matches correctly to:

app.js

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var yourModule = require('yourFile');
app.get('/your_path', yourModule.yourFunction);
```

For me, I ran into this issue when copy pasting a module into another module for testing, needed to change the `exports.xxxx` at the top of the file.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same error. The problem was in the export and import of the modules.

Example of my solution:

Controller (File: posts.js)

```
exports.getPosts = (req, res) => {
    res.json({
        posts: [
            { tittle: 'First posts' },
            { tittle: 'Second posts' },
        ]
    });
};
```

Router (File: posts.js)

```
const express = require('express');
const { getPosts } = require('../controllers/posts');

const routerPosts = express.Router();
routerPosts.get('/', getPosts);

exports.routerPosts = routerPosts;
```

Main (File: app.js)

```
const express = require('express');
const morgan = require('morgan');
const dotenv = require('dotenv');
const { routerPosts } = require('./routes/posts');

const app = express();
const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;

dotenv.config();

// Middleware
app.use(morgan('dev'));

app.use('/', routerPosts);

app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`A NodeJS API is listining on port: ${port}`);
});
```

Running the application (chrome output)

```
// 20200409002022
// http://localhost:3000/

{
  "posts": [
    {
      "tittle": "First posts"
    },
    {
      "tittle": "Second posts"
    }
  ]
}
```

Console Log

```
jmendoza@jmendoza-ThinkPad-T420:~/IdeaProjects/NodeJS-API-Course/Basic-Node-API$ npm run dev

> node-api@1.0.0 dev /home/jmendoza/IdeaProjects/NodeJS-API-Course/Basic-Node-API
> nodemon app.js

[nodemon] 2.0.3
[nodemon] to restart at any time, enter `rs`
[nodemon] watching path(s): *.*
[nodemon] watching extensions: js,mjs,json
[nodemon] starting `node app.js`
A NodeJS API is listining on port: 3000
GET / 304 5.093 ms - -
GET / 304 0.714 ms - -
GET / 304 0.653 ms - -
[nodemon] restarting due to changes...
[nodemon] starting `node app.js`
A NodeJS API is listining on port: 3000
GET / 200 4.427 ms - 62
GET / 304 0.783 ms - -
GET / 304 0.642 ms - -
```

Node Version

```
jmendoza@jmendoza-ThinkPad-T420:~/IdeaProjects/NodeJS-API-Course/Node-API$ node -v
v13.12.0
```

NPM Version

```
jmendoza@jmendoza-ThinkPad-T420:~/IdeaProjects/NodeJS-API-Course/Node-API$ npm -v
6.14.4
```

Comment: Please don't post images of code. Post as text instead.

Answer (score 3):

What happened to me is I was exporting a function like this:

```
module.exports = () => {
    const method = async (req, res) => {
    }
    return {
        method
    }
}
```

but I was calling it like this:

```
const main = require('./module');
```

instead

```
const main = require('./module')();
```

Answer (score 3):

check your closing tags in your model, it may be that you have defined a callback in another callback

Answer (score 3):

My problem was a mistake in importing:

I imported my function into the `router/index.js` like below:

```
const { index } = require('../controllers');
```

and used it like this:

```
router.get('/', index.index);
```

This was my mistake. I must have used this:

```
router.get('/', index);
```

So I changed it to the line above and my problem got solved.

Answer (score 3):

I ran into this issue too, my issues I did not add {} to my export in the controller file.

something like this,

`module.exports = {createVendor};`

Answer (score 1):

This thing also happened with my code, but somehow I solved my problem. I checked my routes folder (where my all endpoints are their). I would recommend you check your routes folder file and check whether you forgot to add your particular router link.

Answer (score 1):

(1) Make sure that you have imported the corresponding controller file in router file

(2) Make sure that the function name written in the any of the `router.get()` or `router.post()` in `router.js` file is exactly same as the function name written in the corresponding controller file

(3) Make sure that you have written
`module.exports=router;` at the bottom of `router.js` file

Answer (score 1):

Had the same error in my project and realised that I ommitted "s" in the module.export controller

I used

```
module.export = launchesRouter
```

Instead of

```
module.exports = launchesRouter
```

I added "s" and my code compiled

Answer (score 1):

For me in a react app, the error was a result of wrong spelling e.g.

I had already created the route -

```
app.get("/scream/:screamId", getScream);
```

But what I called was

```
export.getScreams = (req, res) => {...}
```

Comment: For my case, i accidentally put the () which is for execution and not the reference. When i removed (), it took the method reference and everything worked smoothly

Answer (score 1):

Use `app.set` not `app.get`

```js
app.set('view engine', 'ejs')
```

Answer (score 0):

node js and express 4
use this sequences

```
express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

module.exports = router;
```

last line returns this type of error

Answer (score 0):

In my case I was trying to 'get' from express app. Instead I had to do SET.

```
app.set('view engine','pug');
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that

When you import some modules from other folders for instance,

```
 const { test } = require('./ImportedModule/auth')


 app.post("/post/:id", test);
```

You should double-check that you imported the test from ImportedModule/auth
is exist in ImportedModule/auth Module.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem.
I was trying to import the controller file from the controller folder that I created for other normal controller
But actually, I was needed to import it from the middleware folder. You might have that issue.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem in my project.

And I found out I was missing `{}` on the import.

Answer (score 0):

Error:

> Route.get() requires a callback function but got a [object String]

I was getting same problem, I forgot to use the keyword require eg.

```
const auth = require('./middleware/auth');
```

Answer (score 0):

I know it's too late to post this answer but I want to give you something even better and make you do lesser work, it's obvious that this error came when you misspell a function in the controller. so for the VSC users always create your controller function and export them like you always do. but in the router.js don't import them. just go writing your routers and when you reach the function name VSC will import the function just by typing the first 3 letters so let VSC do the job for you to avoid this kind of problem. it's easy it's clean and less frustrating. hope you understand me, guys !!

Answer (score 0):

You will get this error if the function being called either isn't spelled correctly or doesn't actually exist. Check those two first to save tons of time.

Answer (score 0):

Verify that all of the imported methods are defined and spelled correctly.

Answer (score 0):

In TypeScript, I had a similar issue. Haven't found a better workaround than putting the specific piece of code that triggered it in another file. Maybe it's related to some sort of circular import, I really don't know.

Answer (score 0):

few among the course of the problem include

incomplete code (so check and reconfirm your code) for example under

```
catch(err){
        res.status(500).json({message: err});
    }
```

rectify

```
catch(err){
        res.status(500).json({message: err.message});
    }
```

difference of just .message

also check to see if you have include `module.exports = xxx`

Answer (score 0):

Please check the following to fix this error `Route.get() requires callback functions`

1. Is the `module` exists that you are calling in your `router.get()`? //commonly from your routing file.
2. Are you sending res back?  in both cases, if you are using an `if-else` block
3. have you imported the correct file?
4. is your `route` unique?

Recheck all these hopes this will solve your problem, in my case accidentally deleted the module in the corresponding controller.

Answer (score 0):

You should add next() in each of your callback functions. It worked for my error.

```
`module.exports ={
  all: function(req, res, next){
    res.send('All todos');
    next()
  },
  viewOne: function(req, res, next){
    console.log('Viewing '+req.params.id);
    next()

  },
  create: function(req, res, next){
    console.log('Todo created');
    next()

  },
  destroy: function(req, res, next){
    console.log('Todo deleted');
    next()

  },
  edit: function(req, res, next){
    console.log('Todo '+req.params.id+' updated');
    next()

  }
};`
```

Answer (score 0):

I also got the same problem , check the function you call , if you use arrow function and you have wrote the inside of {} , definitly you should write return , otherwise you will get this error.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

you must make sure you are exporting your code by module.exports = a

considering a is a function or variable or anything, The following is a way to export one variable or one function.

src/hello.js

```
function a() {
  console.log("first function");
  } 
module.exports=a
```

src/usinghello.js

```
const a=require('./hello.js');
a();
```

Now in the terminal inside src directory if you run

```
Node usinghello.js
```

you see the output

```
"first function"
```

Please it is quite a bit different if you want to export 2 or n number of functions or variables. I think you might want to use destructuring.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you have exported the main function in the `routes/todo` file

You should be looking into adding this line

```
module.export = router;
```

Answer (score -1):

My suggestion, if you are still using `const XXX = require('library or ./path')` when using `module.exports` to export multiple functions use an ES6 arrow function.

For example:

```
module.exports = () => { 
    
    const  getPosts = (req, res ) =>{
        res.send('THIS WORKS!');
    }

    const getPost = async (req, res) => { 
        const { id } = req.params;
    
        try {
            const post = await PostMessage.findById(id);
            
            res.status(200).json(post);
        } catch (error) {
            res.status(404).json({ message: error.message });
        }
    }

 }
```

then Import:

```
const getPosts = require('../controllers/posts.js');
```

Answer (score -1):

You just need to write these features like this:

**todoRouter.get('/', ()=> todo.all);**

and everything will be fine