# I searched but couldn't find a solution Route.get() requires a callback function but got a [object Undefined]

Tags: node.js, express

I'm making a blog, but I am facing such an error. Where is it going wrong?

route

```
var express = require("express");
var router = express.Router();
var controller = require("../controllers/CategoriesController");

router.get("/", controller.categories);
router.get("/windows", controller.windows);

module.exports = router;
```

controller

```
var path = require("path");

module.exports.categories = function (req, res) {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, "../categories.html"));
};

module.exports.windows = function (req, res) {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, "../windows.html"));
};
```

Here is the error message that I get.

```
Error: Route.get() requires a callback function but got a [object Undefined]
    at Route.<computed> [as get] (C:\Users\Ufuk\Desktop\NodeJs Atıştırmalar\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:202:15)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Ufuk\Desktop\NodeJs Atıştırmalar\app_server\routes\CategoriesRoupress\lib\router\index.js:510:19)te.js:5:8)                                                                                          te.js:5:8)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1158:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1178:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1002:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:901:14)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1044:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:77:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Ufuk\Desktop\NodeJs Atıştırmalar\app.js:6:23)
[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
```

Comment: could you `console.log(controller)` and tell me the output? It could be a false path you have given

Comment: None of the answers in the question of the exact same title helped you?  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36558909/route-get-requires-callback-functions-but-got-a-object-undefined

Comment: Simple self debugging step #1, add `console.log(typeof controller.categories, controller.categories)` right after `var controller = require("../controllers/CategoriesController");` and see what you actually have.  Also, learn how to replace all instances of `var` with either `const` or `let`.  Shouldn't be using `var` any more.