# Error: Route.get() requires a callback function but got a [object Undefined] - search express

Tags: node.js, function, callback, require

I'm trying to fix a search functionality with query (express nodeJS) but I get this error message... Any ideas what I'm missing?

Thanks!

the route:

```
const SearchController = require("../controllers/search");
route.get("/search/limit", SearchController.searchLimit);
```

the search function:

```
const Product = require("../models/Product");

const searchLimit = async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const { keywords } = req.query;
    keywords = keywords.toLowerCase();
    Product.findAll(
      { where: { keywords: { [Op.like]: "%" + term + "%" } } },
      { limit: 5 }
    )
      .then((output) => res.send("search result", { output }))
      .catch((error) => console.log(error));
  } catch (err) {
    coneole.log(err);
    return err;
  }
};

module.export = { searchLimit };
```

the error message:

```
Error: Route.get() requires a callback function but got a [object Undefined]
```

Comment: duplicate of [this?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36558909/route-get-requires-callback-functions-but-got-a-object-undefined)

Comment: You have a typo -- it should be `module.exports`, not `module.export`.