# Javascript - Error: Route.post() requires a callback function but got a [object Promise]

Tags: javascript, node.js, callback

One of my express routes is giving me the following error:

```
Error: Route.post() requires a callback function but got a [object Promise]
```

It's because of the last line in `controllerFunction`:

```js
// IN CONTROLLER.JS
exports.controllerFunction = async (req, res) => {
    //Get some values
    let foos = await User.somefunction();
    
    for(foo in foos){
        //Call some async void functions
    }
    res.status(200).send('DONE')
}

...

// IN ROUTER.JS
router.post('/', validation, validate, checkLoggedIn, checkUserPermission(1), async(req, res, next) => {
    try{
        await controller.controllerFunction(req, res)
    } catch (error) {
        next(error);
    }
});
```

I figured I need to return a callback function, but I'm not sure how. The rest of my controller functions look like that and they work because of the `.then()`:

```js
// IN CONTROLLER.JS
exports.getCameras = async (req, res) => {
    await Model.getCameras(req.machine)
        .then(cameras => res.send(cameras));
}
```

But in my `controllerFunction` I can't call `.then()` due to the fact that I need to do some logic beforehand in a for loop, so I need to generate the callback function in some other way.

How could I make `controllerFunction` a callback function?

Comment: (The extra async/await in `exports.getCameras` are unneeded. Also `Model.getCameras` is never returned.)

Comment: See this. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36558909/route-get-requires-callback-functions-but-got-a-object-undefined

Comment: None of the code you posted is causing the error reported. You are probably looking at the wrong place. FWIW, what the error means is that `route.post()` expects a regular function. All the code you've posted pass a regular function (weather it has the async keyword does not matter at all). If we ignore the function body, the code is correct: `router.post('/', validation, validate, checkLoggedIn, async(x,y,z) => {})` since `()=>{}` is a regular function (regardless of the async keyword). Make sure `validation`, `validate` and `checkLoggedIn` are all functions and not a return value

Comment: Also, don't mix `await` and `.then()`. It's bad practice and they do the same thing. (So if you can use `await` you **definitely** can use `.then()`, you saying cannot is wrong, you just don't know how to do it)

Comment: @slebetman so I don't have to use both? Thanks. Also what I mean with "I cannot use it" is because the last async call is made inside the for loop so I can't chain the `.then()` inside since it will be called in every loop.

Comment: @slebetman thanks, you were right. One of the functions in the router header was incorrect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [@slebetman](https://stackoverflow.com/users/167735/slebetman) stated in the comments, one of the functions called in the router was incorrect:

```js
router.post('/', validation, validate, checkLoggedIn, checkUserPermission(1), async(req, res, next) => {}
```

> Make sure validation, validate and checkLoggedIn are all functions and not a return value

`checkUserPermission(1)` was incorrect since that function wasn't expecting any parameters to be passed, changed to `checkUserPermission` and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

try this.

`return res.status(200).send('DONE');`

```js
exports.controllerFunction = async (req, res) => {
    //Get some values
    let foos = await User.somefunction();
    
    for(foo in foos){
        //Call some async void functions
    }

    return res.status(200).send('DONE');
}
```

Comment: Still throwing the same error