# Error to import a controller, but I get expect function but got [object undefined]

Tags: node.js, typescript, express

I have authController.ts file where I import all controllers from, and everything works just fine, but if I try to import refresh controller I get this error Error: Route.get() requires a callback function but got a [object Undefined]

I'm to pass refresh controller to route '/refresh'

[In authController.ts](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P0NpY.png)

### All other controllers works just fine, but refresh controller does not!

[in authRoute](https://i.stack.imgur.com/soWnR.png)

Comment: this problem was solved already , maybe this will help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36558909/route-get-requires-callback-functions-but-got-a-object-undefined

Comment: I saw it, but that isn't my issue, because when I click on the authController.refresh it take me to the refresh controller, also all other controllers from the same file works just fine!