# Unable to Connect MongoDB with Node.js

Tags: node.js, mongodb, backend, crud, rest-client

I recently learned MongoDB and connected it to Node.js, but I encountered an error that I am unable to resolve. I am using VS Code, and a pop-up similar to the following appeared:

""The connection was rejected. Either the requested service isn’t running on the requested server/port, the proxy settings in vscode are misconfigured, or a firewall is blocking requests. Details: RequestError: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:3004.""

```
Route.get() requires a callback function but got a [object Object]
```

My index.js

```
const router = require('./routes/bookRoute')

// connect DB
databaseConnect();

app.use(cors());
app.use(express.json())
app.use(router)


app.listen(PORT, ()=>{
    console.log('Server is running...')
})
```

my controller.js

```
const Book = require('../model/bookSchema');

// get all books
const getBooks = async(req, res) => {
    ...
}

// get specific book
const getBookById = async(req, res) => {
  ...
}

// make new book
const saveBook =  async(req,res) => {
   ..
}
module.exports = {getBooks, getBookById, saveBook}
```

my route.js

```
router.get('/books', getBooks)
router.get('/books/:id', getBookById)
router.post('/books', saveBook)

module.exports = router
```

I able to connecting nodeJs and mongodb and do CRUD operation

Comment: How's your mongodb is running? Is with docker? Also by default mongo will run at `27017` port? Which service is running at `3004`. Update your question with your `databaseConnect` function

Comment: i am not use docker, my mongo run at 27017 and my server run at 3004

Comment: app.listen(3004, ()=>{
    console.log('Server is running...')
})

Comment: Hope this helps.. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36558909/route-get-requires-callback-functions-but-got-a-object-undefined